# How can I discover which user and when an index was created?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a postgres table with duplicated indexes (called `someName` and `someName1`) applied to the same columns. I would like to know which user executed the ddl that created these indexes, and when it happened. Is this possible on postgres?

Comment: Not possible. Postgres does not store this information.

Comment: By default Postgres does not record this information. If you want to do so,  you have a couple of options I know of: 1) [Event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/event-trigger-definition.html) 2) Something like [PGAudit](https://www.pgaudit.org/).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 3) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT

Comment: @Abelisto, that helps if you have the log files that cover the actual object creation. If the log files are out of scope then it doesn't help. I was suggesting things that are more persistent. You would also have to modify `log_line_prefix` to get the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hadn't already set up some kind of auditing or aggressive logging before this happened, then your options are pretty limited.

If you retain WAL files, you could go exploring through those (with pg_waldump and other tools, or by doing PITR) to pinpoint the time.  This will probably not be a quick and painless exercise.  By looking at surrounding changes, or at log files from the same time, you might be able to figure out who was logged on at the time and also had permissions to create the index.